# Gujarati text in Javascript alert box not showing

Tags: javascript

I am trying to display alert box message in Gujarati in my website. I am trying to use the javascript alert for this purpose. 
but gujarati language not showing in alert box

```
<input  type="button" style="margin-left: 0px"  style="border:none" style="color:#999999" style="background-color: #fff0e0" value=" ક્લિક કરો " onclick=javascript:msg1001() /><script language="JavaScript">function msg1001(){alert("(A) વિકલ્પ Assam");}</script></td></tr><td valign="top" width="5%"><br />
```

Answer (score 1):

Open your HTML page in some text editor i recommend [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) set an Encoding to UTF-8 and then pre type the characters again. Run html and it should work fine.

Comment: hi Vuk Vasić
this method 
not working

Comment: Yes it's working you didn't encode it in UTF-8 and retyped characters again  . If you don't belive me download this zip inside is a HTML file working in UTF-8. http://int-char.ag.rs/example.zip

Comment: thanks for your reply
but not working

Answer (score 0):

Here is the HTML of your code. Jsfilddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yelinaung/4eFhh/).

```
<input  type="button" style="margin-left: 0px"  style="border:none" style="color:#999999" style="background-color: #fff0e0" value=" ક્લિક કરો " onclick="msg1001()" />
```

and JS

```
function msg1001(){
    alert("(A) વિકલ્પ Assam");
}
```

Please save your HTML document in using UTF-8 encoding with a proper editor.

Comment: hi mgpyone
i use this
but did not work

Answer (score 0):

Adding a meta tag will work.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
```

Comment: i use this before
but not working

Comment: Its just a problem of encoding. Its working fine here. Add that tag in your HTML.